# Can I perform a transaction across two MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, transactions

Can I do?

```
Start transaction;

insert into db1.table1 (field1) values (100),(100);

insert into db2.table2 (field2) values (100),(100);

commit;
```

Or will that not work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can:

> MySQL 5.0.3 and up provides
>   server-side support for XA
>   transactions. **Currently, this support
>   is available for the InnoDB storage
>   engine.** The MySQL XA implementation is
>   based on the X/Open CAE document
>   Distributed Transaction Processing:
>   The XA Specification. This document is
>   published by The Open Group and
>   available at
>   http://www.opengroup.org/public/pubs/catalog/c193.htm.
>   [Ref: XA Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html)