# MySQL transaction over two databases on different servers

Tags: mysql, transactions

Is it possible to make a MySQL transaction that changes databases on different servers?

I would need to:

1. insert into the first database
2. select from the first database
3. insert into the second database
4. if any of these fails, revert to the original state

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I to a transaction across two MySQL databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738685/can-i-to-a-transaction-across-two-mysql-databases)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate as the question states on different servers not just different databases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As observed above, this question is very similar to [Can I to a transaction across two MySQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5738685)  Whilst that question referred to different databases on the same server, [its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738749) still applies.

Indeed, as documented under [XA Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/xa.html):

> Support for [XA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_xa) transactions is available for the [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) storage engine.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> XA supports distributed transactions, that is, the ability to permit multiple separate transactional resources to participate in a global transaction. Transactional resources often are RDBMSs but may be other kinds of resources.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> Some examples of distributed transactions:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - An application performs actions that involve different database servers, such as a MySQL server and an Oracle server (or multiple MySQL servers), where actions that involve multiple servers must happen as part of a global transaction, rather than as separate transactions local to each server.